# Current Date in Java 1.4

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, java1.4

For getting Current date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format I am using the below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
                Date date = new Date();
                 String date3= sdf.format(date);
                date = sdf.parse(date3);
```

but everytime I print the date ,it gives me wrong and random output

**output**

```
Currentd Date:: 49/22/2013
```

**output**

```
Currentd Date:: 07/22/2013
```

Kindly suggest as what I should use to get current date.
The Java Version I am using is 1.4

Comment: FYI, the older [version 1.6.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/1.6.2/) of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is compatible with Java 1.4. You will find that much easier to work with than java.util.Date/Calendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `"mm/dd/yyyy"` into `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. `m`(lowercase) is use for minutes not for month. For month you should use `M`(uppercase)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `MM` instead of `mm` in the format pattern which will give you month instead of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
`MM/dd/yyyy`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

```
MM  -  Month
mm  -  Minute
```

Answer (score 1):

m = Minute

M = Month

Thus you have to use `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); //2014/08/06 16:00:22
OR
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //2014/08/06 16:00:22